# Literal does not match format string

Tags: c#, oracle10g, ora-01861

I am trying to insert data in oracle express 10 g table.

My table contains following Columns:

```
Field Name                           Data Type

 ATDATE                               DATE
 ATTIME                               VARCHAR2(5)
 EMPNO                                NUMBER(8)
 INOUTIND                             CHAR(1)
 TRTNO                                CHAR(3)
 FLAG                                 NUMBER(2)
 STATUS                               CHAR(1)
 LUPDT                                DATE
```

Now when I am trying to insert data from my C# Windows application I am getting error

> ORA-01861 : literal does not match format string"

So how can I solve it?

I am writing insert command in the Form itself using `OracleCommand`.

---

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO TMPATND values(:Atdate,:Attime,:Empno,:Inoutind,:Trtno,:Flag,:Status,:Lupdt)", con); 

:Atdate,:Attime etc are parameters. e.g: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":Atdate","20120103");
```

In which format I should pass the date? ( dd/mm/yyyy or yyyymmdd or others)

Comment: OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO TMPATND values(:Atdate,:Attime,:Empno,:Inoutind,:Trtno,:Flag,:Status,:Lupdt)", con);   

:Atdate,:Attime etc are parameters.
e.g:
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":Atdate","20120103");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you perform the insert using parameters, you won't have to worry about the format of the string.

However, if that is not an option, you can use:

```
myDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yy").ToUpper()
```